# how to solve value not binding issue using observable array and forEach binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application

Iam using knockout js and asp.net mvc (vs2013) with entity framework 
First of all I have an index page(masterViewModel) where I declare all my sub view models

In addition ,  have a viewmodel and a functon that makes an ajax call to server side , collects information from server side , insets into an observable array and binds elements of that array to view 
the datacoming from server side shows , three objects , the binding works but instead of binding  three different assistant driver namesto the view it binds the same value three times(object 2) after looping 
through object 0 and 1 . At the moment my current output is

smith 
 smith 
 smith

this is my call to server side in knockout

```
function populateDrivers() {
    if (!masterViewModel.isAuthenticated()) return;

    $.when(getSecureData("/api/Drivers/?driverId="))
    .done(function (resp) {
        masterViewModel.vehicleDetail.assistantDriverList(resp.assistantDriverList)

       ko.utils.arrayMap(resp.assistantDriverList, function (obj) {
       //ko.utils.arrayForEach(resp.assitantDriverList, function (obj)
       //arrayMap
       masterViewModel.FleetInfoVM.vehicleDetail.assistantDriverName(obj.assistantDriverName);
       masterViewModel.FleetInfoVM.vehicleDetail.carRegNumber(obj.CarRegNumber);
       masterViewModel.FleetInfoVM.vehicleDetail.make(obj.Make);
       masterViewModel.FleetInfoVM.vehicleDetail.Model(obj.Model);      
        });

    });

}
```

and this my binding in the html

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Assistant Name</th>

</tr>
</thead>
```

```
<tr>

    <td data-bind="text: $root.FleetInfoVM.vehicleDetail.assistantDriverName"> </td>

    <td class="td-actions">
        <a class="btn btn-small" data-bind="click: $root.vehicleDetail.edit" title="Edit">
            <i class="icon-edit"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-small" ">

        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-small">

        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and these are my view models

```
function MasterViewModel() {
        var pvm = this;
        mvm.loginVM = new LoginViewModel();
        mvm.VehicleVM = new vehicleViewModel();
        mvm.topManagerVM = new TopManagerViewModel();
        mvm.FleetInfoVM = new FleetInfoViewModel
    }

   MasterViewModel = new MasterViewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(MasterViewModel, document.getElementById("htmlTop"));


FleetInfoViewModel
=========================================================================

function FleetInfoViewModel
{
  var fiv = this; 

   fiv.branch id = ko.observable(0);
   fiv.branch name = ko.observable(0);
   fiv.location = ko.observable("");
   fiv.driverDetail = new DriverViewModel();
   fiv.vehicleDetail = new vehicleViewModel(); 

}
function DriverViewModel() {
    var drv = this;
    drv.driverId = ko.observable(0);
    drv.driverName = ko.observable("");
}
function  vehicleViewModel{
    vvm.assitantDriverList =  ko.observable([]);
    vvm.assistantDriverName = ko.observable("");
    vvm.regNumber = ko.observable(0);
    vvm.make = ko.observable(""); 
    vvm.model = ko.observable("");
   }
```

Comment: That's too long and too broad. Isolate the problem first (is the server doing its part correctly? Is the client getting what it should? etc...), and ask again

Comment: yes it is because the other names appear then dissapear leaving the last name displaying thrice e,g smith smith smith instead of Jones , Jameson , Smith

Comment: where is your `foreach` binding in html?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in your `arrayMap`. Whilst you're iterating the results therein, you're still only binding back to the same object (hence why you're overwriting the result on each iteration). You should be creating an instance of `vehicleViewModel` in there, and pushing that to an observableArray. Something like

```
var vehicleList = ko.observableArray();

// arrayMap returns an array of whatever you return therein. In this case
// an instance of your vehicleDetail viewModel.
vehicleList = ko.utils.arrayMap(resp.assistantDriverList, function (obj) {
    var vehicleDetail = new vehicleViewModel();
    vehicleDetail.assistantDriverName(obj.assistantDriverName);
    vehicleDetail.carRegNumber(obj.CarRegNumber);
    vehicleDetail.make(obj.Make);
    vehicleDetail.Model(obj.Model);      
    return vehicleDetail;
});
```

Comment: thanks @Wil it seems the problem was actually to do with the binding value